# show array within object all at once

Tags: jquery, json, each

i tried to displaying json data that have object inside aray inside object, but all at once

```
 "data_nasabah": [
        {
            "nasabah_id": "0000-000-0098",
            "nama_nasabah": "nasabah 1",
            "nama_identitas": "KTP",
            "sub_data_detail": [
                {
                    "no_rekening": "029000003402394",
                    "deskripsi_produk": "tabungan"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
                "nasabah_id": "0000-000-0098",
                "nama_nasabah": "nasabah 1",
                "nama_identitas": "KTP",
                "sub_data_detail": [
                    {
                        "no_rekening": "0293402394",
                        "deskripsi_produk": "tabungan"
                    }
                ]
        }
  ]
```

i tried this code of  mine, but get an error read properti of sub_data_detail, i know im gonna got an error, cuz i never do a doube loop before

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
       <title>test</title>
      </head>
     <body>
     <P>hello world!!!</P>
     <div class="row" id="input">

     <select id="select"></select>

     </div>


      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON('json.json', function(data){

        $.each(data, function(i, loop){
            $('#input').append(`
                    <input type="text" value="`+ loop.nasabah_id +`"></input>
                    <input type="text" value="`+ loop.nama_nasabah +`"> 
      </input>
                    <input type="text" value="`+ loop.nama_identitas +`"> 
      </input>
                       `)
                   $.each(loop[0].sub_data_detail, function(i, row){
                       $('#select').html(`
                               <option value="`+ row.no_rekening +`">`+ 
      row.no_rekening +`</option>
                           `);
                   })
               });
       });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

how to show all of this data at once using jquery each function

Comment: Please share your code that you tried

Comment: ive edited my code, add an HTMl, and jquery ive tried, please help, i read documentastion about jquery, cant find any solusian and honnestly, i kinda new about  programer

Comment: Actually you're superclose I think. Remove the `[0]` after `loop` in the second `$.each`

Comment: actualy, the data was append to select, but only the last json data, the first one is not showing

Comment: Hey I added an answer please take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem. First your JSON needed curly braces before "data_nesbah" for proper JSON syntax to declare it as an array object with elements in it. Then I changed `$.each(data` to `$.each(data.data_nasabah`so jquery would iterate through the correct array object. I also changed this

```
           $.each(loop[0].sub_data_detail, function(i, row){
               $('#select').html(`
                       <option value="`+ row.no_rekening +`">`+ row.no_rekening +`</option>
                   `);
           })
```

to this, since the .html() didnt append a new option like you wanted.

```
        $.each(element.sub_data_detail, function(i, row) {
            var o = new Option(row.no_rekening, row.no_rekening);
            $(o).html(row.no_rekening);
            $('#select').append(o);
        })
```

here's the json and the code.

```
{
  "data_nasabah": [
    {
      "nasabah_id": "0000-000-0098",
      "nama_nasabah": "nasabah 1",
      "nama_identitas": "KTP",
      "sub_data_detail": [
        {
          "no_rekening": "029000003402394",
          "deskripsi_produk": "tabungan"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nasabah_id": "0000-000-0098",
      "nama_nasabah": "nasabah 1",
      "nama_identitas": "KTP",
      "sub_data_detail": [
        {
          "no_rekening": "0293402394",
          "deskripsi_produk": "tabungan"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

html code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <P>hello world!!!</P>
    <div class="row" id="input">

        <select id="select"></select>

    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {

            $.each(data.data_nasabah, function(index, element) {
                $('#input').append(`
                    <input type="text" value="` + element.nasabah_id + `"></input>
                    <input type="text" value="` + element.nama_nasabah + `"> 
      </input>
                    <input type="text" value="` + element.nama_identitas + `"> 
      </input>
                       `)
                $.each(element.sub_data_detail, function(i, row) {
                    var o = new Option(row.no_rekening, row.no_rekening);
                    $(o).html(row.no_rekening);
                    $('#select').append(o);
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
</body></html>
```